# Windows Store App - installed update - integrity issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I experience a very weird issue that drives me insane. It is hard to explain and to believe but I'll try to explain.

My developed app was installed at a local pc (not the developer pc) for testing. I then made some changes to the application. I deinstalled the app at the testing machine and installed the new version. The strange thing is, that at the testing machine I still see the previous version without the changes.

I hope you can understand.

Comment: how did you install it ? I am using Metro Sideloader and never had any problems, http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/CompuSight-Metro-App-b31b65da

Comment: I created an app package in Visual Studio and installed it via Powershell. Never had problems using this method.

Comment: try to uninstall it from that machine and then clean instal

Comment: that's what I've tried

Comment: sorry, didn't read very carefully :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved the proplem. It has nothing to do with the installation process. Anyway it was related to a very weird Windows behaviour. I'll try to explain:

On the developer machine (PC1) the language setting is German(Germany). At the machine where the app is installed (PC2) the language was German(Austria). With these slight but important difference I got a FormatException when parsing a string to a double value at PC2 (',' <-> '.'). After changing the language settings at PC2 the issue was solved.

Without remote debugging I wouldn't have detected this behaviour.